# C# class inheritance doesn't work

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    public class ParentClass
    {


    }

    public class childClass : ParentClass
    {
        public int Normal()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

---

SomeWhere else:

```
ParentClass parentc = new ParentClass();

parentc.Normal(); //<-- I can't call the function normal!
```

I need help, to use it.

Comment: Yes, because your making a `ParentClass`, not a `childClass`?

Comment: You cannot call a child class method from parent. But can call parent class method from child. @PiDEV

Comment: I've downvoted this because it doesn't show any effort on OP's part to research at least the very basic of inheritance.

Answer (score 7):

`Parent` does not have a method `Normal`, so you can't call it.  By basic logic, a parent does not inherit its child's methods; it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Move the normal method to the parent class:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public int Normal()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class childClass : ParentClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to Create Refferance of Child Class to Acess the Normal(); function .

```
childClass obj=new childClass();
obj.Normal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this;

```
    class ParentClass
       {
          public int Normal()
          {
            return 1;
          }
       }
    // Derived class
       class ChildClass: ParentClass
       {
          public int someMethod()
          { 
             return Normal();         
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **cast the object down**.
You do it when you need to apply a child's function to a parent object.
In order to do that, you need to declare you want to cast the object later by using the child constructor when creating the parent, like so:

```
class foo{}
class goo:foo{ public void DoStuff(){} }
/*.... In the main program ..... */
foo a = new goo(); // Declaring the a, which is of type foo, might be used as a goo later on.
```

And for useage, cast it down.

```
((goo)a).DoStuff();
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a child class method from parent. But can call parent class method from child.

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    public class ParentClass
    {
        public int Normal()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class childClass : ParentClass
    {
        Normal(); // which calls the method in Base class(ParentClass)
        //base.Normal(); //or this one in which base tells that the method is in base class
    } 
}
```